# Send SMS programmatically on my Computer using my Phone

Tags: sms

I am looking for a (web) app that allows me to send bulk SMS using my phone. I am not looking for an internet SMS gateway that would give me a new number.

The app should also allow me to import an Excel/CSV file with the numbers, names, and other custom fields which then get dynamically replaced with the actual values.

So far I tested Microsoft’s My Phone App and MightyText, which both work; yet, they do now allow importing data or custom fields.

Is there anything out there?

Comment: Please review answer

Comment: What phone are you using? Android or iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned Microsoft's Your Phone, so I will assume the phone is running an Android OS.

While I don't know of specific tools, I use [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) to automatically receive and send SMS Text messages via a gmail account.

I live in the US, and I have an old phone, hooked up to a SIM with my old country's phone number. it doesn't leave my home, and any incoming SMS text is sent to mt wife and mine email addresses.

This way we can still connect to SMS based 2FA solutions that must work within that country's phone system.

It's rather easy to create any flow you need, I'm assuming you can create something that listens to an email message with the list and based on that list send SMS Text Messages

Answer (score 0):

ITNOA

If you want a programmatically solution you can see such Q&A like below

- [sending sms from windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052545/1539100)
- [Sending SMS through Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10689378/1539100)
- [How can I send SMS messages through PC programatically?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/32435/362514)

But I think production ready application make life easier for example, I think [Android Bulk SMS Sender Unlimited](https://www.lantechsoft.com/android-bulk-sms-sender.html) can meet your requirements, and you can use your number in your phone, and sending SMS from Windows.

The description of this application:

Android Bulk SMS Sender is a multiple SMS sending tool from Multiple Android phones through a single platform at once. You can send Thousands of SMS from your PC through connected Android Phones. You need to install 'SMS Sender Modem Pro' App in your phone to get connected to the Android Bulk SMS Sender. You can import the contact list from the files (excel and text files) on your computer or you can enter contacts manually. You can send SMS to any number recipients without any constraints from the software. Android Bulk SMS Sender allows you to send INTERNATIONAL SMS in BULK with the feature of adding country code as prefix to Mobile Numbers. Android SMS sender also allows you to customize SMS with many fields such as (Mobile Number, Name etc). It allows you to select mobile number out of all connected mobile phones through which you want to send SMS from PC. Android Bulk SMS Sender includes many features such as delay in SMS to be delivered.Android Bulk SMS Sender sends SMS from pc to mobile.

Android Bulk SMS Sender acts as an advanced marketing tool in the market, making it easier to send promotional messages and links. You can send Personalized message to all the contacts. For example, you can add the name of contacts in the message for personal touch.It also keepsa Log file for Sent and Failed SMS with number, corresponding message and Dates of SMS sent. The unique feature of Android Bulk SMS Sender is that itsends SMS to All DND/NON-DND Mobile Numbers. This SMS sending softwaresends SMS to individuals or list of phone numbers. Android Bulk SMS Sender is compatible with both Windows 7 and Windows 10. It only requires you to have the SIM in your phone and No data connection is required for its working. It supports Multi Lingual SMS so that you can send SMS in French, Italian, Japanese, Arabic, Hindi, Gujarati, Urdu, Punjabi, Bengali, Tamil, Telugu, Kannada, Malayalam, German and many Others.

IMPORTANT NOTE: "SMS Sender Modem Pro App" required in the Android Phone.

You can see features in site, for example `You can also send unique PERSONALIZED SMS for each recipients using Excel Data`

Some other application

- [Bulk SMS Software - Professional](https://www.datadoctor.biz/bulk-sms.html)
- [Bulk SMS Software](http://www.bulksmssoftware.net/)